# Type safety for REST endpoints

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

In SvelteKit we can define REST endpoints like this in a `+server.svelte` file:

```
export const POST = (async ({ request }) => {
    // implementation
}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

I was wondering how I get type safety for this method. For instance I would like to ensure the request body is of form:

```
interfce Person {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
}
```

Also my answer from the endpoint should be of a certain type. Can't I ensure that with the `RequestHandler` type?

Answer (score 0):

In your said function, to guarantee type safety for your body, you can do the following:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
}

export const POST = (async (request) => {
  const body: Person = await request.json() //...
}) as RequestHandler;
```